# SDK CS:GO (Hammer editor): Maximum rounds and round time

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hammer

I am making a map in CS:GO with SDK. Is there a way to make it so that the map starts with a specific number of rounds and round time (also without warmup if possible)? It is a 1v1 map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `point_servercommand` to set `mp_maxrounds` and other config settings in Hammer, but I wouldn't do it this way.

A better way is a map specific config:

```
path/to/server/maps/cfg/your_map_name.cfg
```

You can put all settings you need in this file and it'll override the given settings from the default `server.cfg` for this map. When another map is loaded with no specific config the `server.cfg` will be used again.
I'm not really sure what config settings you want to use, but `mp_maxrounds` and such are no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you can't do that. You would always be able to put in whatever time you want over console-commands. That is because things like roundtime are determined by the Server, not the map.

However, you can put standard round time and such in the config file, yet it only is used if the map is run as a Custom Gamemode, otherwise the game will use the standard config file.

There is an own Page on the [official ValveSoftware site](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/CSGO_Custom_Game_Mode) dedicated to doing this and which commands you can use.

The commands you probably want are `mp_maxrounds`, `mp_warmuptime`, `mp_timelimit` and `mp_roundtime`.

Note: `mp_timelimit` will end the match even if mid-round in case it runs out.